# How to make Vim continue bullet points?

Tags: vim

When I use Mediawiki-syntax first-level bullet points, pressing enter key shows a bullet point for the next line as well:

```
* <CR>
*
```

But when I have the second-level bullet points, it just starts a new blank line

```
** <CR>
(blank line)
```

What option/expression do I have to change/program to make it put `**` in the second line?

I have `set autoindent` in my vimrc, not sure if that is the one that does the repeating of `*` with the enter key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
setlocal formatoptions=ctnqro
setlocal comments+=n:*,n:#
```

It works that way in [vimwiki](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2226).

Comment: If he only adds n:* that should mean that its only a single * that counts as a comment line. And since that already works for him, he probably already has that in `comments`

Comment: Sam, just apply those commands on a new buffer -- you'll see double stars just work.

Answer (score 1):

I think Vim should at least be able to do this if it interprets your bullet points as starting comments.

You can check `:he 'comments'` and `:he format-comments` to learn more about Vim's slightly tricky comment definitions.

You can at least get it working for two asterisks by doing `:set comments+=:**`. Also `:se formatoptions?` should include r